# Creating a new column using scores from past years (which is in the same dataframe)

Tags: r

I'm sorry if this question has already been answered, but I don't really know how to phrase my question.

I have a data frame structured in this way:

| country | year | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| France | 2020 | 10 |
| France | 2019 | 9 |
| Germany | 2020 | 15 |
| Germany | 2019 | 14 |

I would like to have a new column called `previous_year_score` that would look into the data frame looking for the "score" of a `country` for the "`year` - 1". In this case France 2020 would have a `previous_year_score` of 9, while France 2019 would have a `NA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(prev_val = ifelse(year - lag(year) == 1, lag(score), NA))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   country [2]
  country  year score prev_val
  <chr>   <int> <int>    <int>
1 France   2019     9       NA
2 Germany  2019    14       NA
3 France   2020    10        9
4 Germany  2020    15       14
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `match()` for this. I imagine there are plenty of other solutions too.

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(country = c("France", "France", "Germany", "Germany"
), year = c(2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L), score = c(10L, 9L, 15L, 
14L), prev_score = c(9L, NA, 14L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Solution:

```
i <- match(paste(df[[1]],df[[2]]-1),paste(df[[1]],df[[2]]))
df$prev_score <- df[i,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   arrange(country, year) %>%
    group_by(country) %>% 
    mutate(prev_val = case_when(year - lag(year) == 1 ~ lag(score)))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   country [2]
  country  year score prev_val
  <chr>   <int> <int>    <int>
1 France   2019     9       NA
2 France   2020    10        9
3 Germany  2019    14       NA
4 Germany  2020    15       14
```